# Select fields Conditionally in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to select from mongoose for example the fields `mobileNumber` and `email` if the user type in the same schema is `admin` and don't select them if the user type is 'individual'. All these fields are in the same schema. So, how can I select conditionally in mongoDB ?

Here is my Implementation:

```
const userData = await userProvider.findOne(
  { _id: userId },
  'mobileNumber email'
);
```

where `findOne` is a function that takes 1st argument as filter and second argument as select fields

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is another simpler way but you can use `$cond` in a project stage to keep the value if is `admin` or else `$$REMOVE` like this:

```
db.collection.find(
{ _id: userId },
{
  "_id": 0,
  "type": 1,
  "email": {
    "$cond": [
      {
        "$eq": [
          "$type",
          "admin"
        ]
      },
      "$email",
      "$$REMOVE"
    ]
  },
  "mobileNumber": {
    "$cond": [
      {
        "$eq": [
          "$type",
          "admin"
        ]
      },
      "$mobileNumber",
      "$$REMOVE"
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TJH4DC01wDO)